# pkg_add not working propely on OpenBSD

Tags: openbsd

Would like to have emacs installed on my server running OpenBSD instead of just vi, reason because I am used to emacs.

I am compleatly new to OpenBSD so I started reading the documentation, after tried `pkg_add emacs`, this is the result

```
https://cdn.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/6.4/packages-stable/amd64/: ftp: cdn.openbsd.org: no address associated with name
https://cdn.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/6.4/packages/amd64/: ftp: cdn.openbsd.org: no address associated with name
https://cdn.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/6.4/packages/amd64/: empty
Can't find emacs
```

So I go back to documentation, I read that

```
There is also an ambiguity related to ports with multiple branches.  
For instance `pkg_add python' is ambiguous, as there are several versions of
python in the ports tree.  So is `pkg_add postfix'.  The special form
`pkgname%branch' can be used to restrict matches to a branch matching the
pkgpath(7).

The above ambiguities can be resolved using `pkg_add postfix%stable' and
`pkg_add python%3.4', respectively.
```

So I try installing python3.4 using (as the documentation) `pkg_add python%3.4`, but get the same error as before when trying with emacs.

Now I am certain that there is something wrong in the config of `pkg_add`, but what? I have tried running `pkg_check`, but it just say everything is ok.

Comment: Same for 7.1 with https, ftp or rsync in `/etc/installurl` for any mirror I try from [official mirror list](https://www.openbsd.org/ftp.html)

Comment: Perhaps it's a firewall issue. In my case it is.

Answer (score 2):

Is your network properly configured?  `pkg_add` can't seem to resolve `cdn.openbsd.org` (hence `no address associated with name`), which likely means you either have no DNS server configured (it should be in `/etc/resolv.conf`, which usually is written by `dhclient` if you use DHCP to configure a network interface) or you have it configured but can't reach it because your network connection is down.  Check if your network is up and properly configured and check if you have a nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Answer (score 2):

There must be more to it than that.  I had that problem today (OpenBSD 6.1) but both my network connection and resolv.conf were fine.  I could resolve the host name with nslookup.  When I got tired of screwing around, ***I copied and pasted the ip address returned by nslookup in place of the host name in /etc/installurl***.  That worked fine, and I got my packages installed.